# Segregate the list based on condition that starts with same pattern `string`

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below list where i would like to segregate based on condition where all strings that starts with same string would become a newlist

Eg:-

```
list1 = ["glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/file.h", "glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/ioctl.h", "glibc-2.11.3/lib/crtn.o", "linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h" , "linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h", "test-3.7.10/asm/posix_types.h", "test-3.7.10/dsm/posix_types.h"]
```

Here is my try:-

```
list1 = ["glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/file.h", "glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/ioctl.h", "glibc-2.11.3/lib/crtn.o", "linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h" , "linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h"]

element = list1[0].split("/")[0]

newlist = []
for i in list1:
    if i.startswith(element):
        newlist.append(i)

print newlist
```

o/p:- `['glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/file.h', 'glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/ioctl.h', 'glibc-2.11.3/lib/crtn.o']`

I get the 1st set of paths that starts with same string. I need to loop over for other remaining sets.

Basically What i am looking is , for a 1st iteration i am expecting to get all paths that starts with `glibc-2.11.3` and for 2nd iteration all paths that starts with `linux-libc-headers-2.6.32`..so on. Actually  i need to perform some check on set of same paths (starts with same string) that gets returned. Please help!

Comment: Loop over your list and add any strings that meet your condition to a new list. What part of doing this are you having difficulty with? Could you show us some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @hostingutilities.com, Thanks for you reply. I just updated what i tried.

Comment: If `list1` is sorted you can try to use [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): `[list(g) for _, g in groupby(list1, lambda x: x.split("/", 1)[0])]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) to keep track of your filepaths

```
list1 = ["glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/file.h", "glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/ioctl.h", "glibc-2.11.3/lib/crtn.o", "linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h" , "linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h", "test-3.7.10/asm/posix_types.h", "test-3.7.10/dsm/posix_types.h"]

directories = {}
for filepath in list1:
    key = filepath.split("/")[0]
    directories.setdefault(key, []).append(filepath)

print(directories)
```

Outputs:

```
{'glibc-2.11.3': ['glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/file.h',
                  'glibc-2.11.3/include/sys/ioctl.h',
                  'glibc-2.11.3/lib/crtn.o'],
 'linux-libc-headers-2.6.32': ['linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h',
                               'linux-libc-headers-2.6.32/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h'],
 'test-3.7.10': ['test-3.7.10/asm/posix_types.h',
                 'test-3.7.10/dsm/posix_types.h']}
```

`list(directories.items())` would give you the list of lists you were trying to create, but instead of doing that you can just use `directories.items()` the exact same way you would use a list of lists.

`dictionary.setdefault(key, [])` is a quirky way of saying give me the list at this dictionary key or if there is not already a list there, create a new list and save it in the dictionary under this dictionary key and then give me that. [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Comment: Same logic above should work irrespective of the order of items in `list1` right? I hope it should work for un sorted order as well.

Comment: Yes, the order of items in `list1` doesn't matter. It can be unsorted.