# Delete string if there is a longer string that starts with same pattern

Tags: python

I have a list of values:

```
['27',
 '27.1',
 '27.1.a',
 '27.1.b',
 '27.3.d.28',
 '27.3.d.28.1',
 '27.3.d.28.2',
]
```

I want to keep only the longest values for each "parent" value. That is, delete 27 if there is a 27.something. Delete 27.1. if there is a 27.1.something, etc.

In this case, output should be

```
['27.1.a',
 '27.1.b',
 '27.3.d.28.1',
 '27.3.d.28.2',
]
```

Background info: this is a dataset in which 27 contains the sum of all 27.sth, so I only want to keep the most dissagregated data.

I know that I can find the longest string by

```
lis = ['27',
 '27.1',
 '27.1.a',
 '27.1.b',
 '27.3.d.28',
 '27.3.d.28.1',
 '27.3.d.28.2',
]

ls = max(len(x) for x in lis)       
[x for x in lis if len(x) == le]
```

But I don't know how to do this tree search. I guess something with regex could work but I have no idea where to start. Any hint is appreciated.

I also saw [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74096626/14534411) which works well if I had only one level (one period), but I don't know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: To do the "tree search", you will need to parse your strings and use a more complex comparison. I recommend that you write a function `def keep(s1, s2)` that compares `s1` and `s2` and decides which of them to keep.

Comment: In general, break the problem down to smaller subproblems and solve the smaller problems one at a time.

Comment: I don't think `len(x)` is what you want. `27.1` and `29.2` have the same length. You should split on dot first, then group by common prefixes. You don't need regex

Comment: Do you want the matches only at the beginning or anywhere? For instance, if you have `['27.1', '1.27.1.2']`, should you keep or discard `'27.1'`?

Comment: I like the idea by @Code-Apprentice of making a function and comparing each of them.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes, I thought I could split and then group. I did it with split(expand=True) in a DataFrame, but then I didn't know how to trim by the "parent"rows (e.g. 27).

Comment: @mozway in that case I would like to keep the 27.1 because '1.27.1.2' is another parent that starts with 1.

Comment: @Ignacio thanks, then I believe a simple sorting a comparison of the successive pairs should work. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the match is anchored on the left, a strategy might be to sort the strings, thus the strings will cluster by prefix, then only compare the successive pairs:

```
def is_parent(p, target):
    return p.startswith(target) and len(p)>len(target) and p[len(target)] == '.'

out = []
prev = ''
for s in sorted(lis)+['']:
    if prev and not is_parent(s, prev):
        out.append(prev)
    prev = s

print(out)
```

Output: `['27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2']`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that tree search is required here. You only have to check whether a list value is indeed a longest value, i.e., it is not contained in another value. The following calculation should do what you want (which could be more efficient I guess).

```
values = ['27', '27.1', '27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2']

longest_values = []
for v1 in values:
    # check whether v1 is a longest value
    is_longest_value = True

    # this is the case when v1 is not "in" (string compare) any other value
    for v2 in values:
        if v1 in v2 and len(v1) < len(v2):
            # v1 is not a longest value
            is_longest_value = False
            break

    if is_longest_value:
        longest_values.append(v1)
```

Applying this on the given list results in `longest_values = ['27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2']`.

Comment: Edit: this will not work properly for cases like 27.1 and 1.27.1.2, as in this case you would want to keep the 27.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do (assuming your list `l` is sorted already).
Used `rindex` to get to the immediate parent of current element.

```
d = dict()
for e in l:
  if "." in e:
    k = e[:e.rindex(".")]
    d.pop(k, None)
  d[e] = None
print(list(d.keys()))
```

Output:

```
['27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension, max with a key that determines the length (but assigns -1 if the element does not start with the same value) and then using set to eliminate duplicate values:

```
>>> data = ['27', '27.1', '27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2']
>>> set([max(data, key=lambda s:len(s) if s.startswith(x+".") else -1) for x in data])
{'27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your strings are sorted, you could use zip to pair up each one with its successor and determine if it should be included or not:

```
r = [s for s,n in zip(lis,lis[1:]+[""]) if not n.startswith(s)]

print(r)
['27.1.a', '27.1.b', '27.3.d.28.1', '27.3.d.28.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a solution provided to me in R in case someone using R lands here:

```
lis <- c('27',
        '27.1',
        '27.1.a',
        '27.1.b',
        '27.3.d.28',
        '27.3.d.28.1',
        '27.3.d.28.2')

list <- as.data.frame(lis) %>% arrange(.) %>% mutate(inside = NA)

for(x in 1:(nrow(list)-1)){
  list$inside[x] <- grepl(list$lis[x], list$lis[x+1])
}

list <- list %>% dplyr::filter(inside == FALSE | is.na(inside))
```